# Prevent Subdomains being viewed/crawled

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing, search-engine, google-search

cPanel only allows me to create 'AddOn' domains. I have pointed all my TLDS to the server which saves them under 'public_html/main/sites' directories '/site1.com' , '/site2.com' etc. mainwebsite.com will be served under 'public_html' and all my client sites under 'public_html/main/sites'

It also creates subdomains 'username.mainsite.com' How can i prevent google from indexing those subdomains yet still index the TLDS. And stop users from being able to access the TLD from the subdomain too?

If i created a RewriteRule would google still index the TLD? Or is there a better way to go about this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.site1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site1.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: To clarify: A subdomain `sub.example.com` is saved under `public_html/main/sites/sub`, and therefore can also be accessed through `example.com/main/sites/sub`? And you want to block `example.com/main/sites/sub`, but allow google to still index `sub.example.com`?

Comment: A subdomain is saved under public_html/main/sites/sub and can be accessed via sub.example.com and the TLD also. I just want to be sure google doesnt index the subdomain just the TLD and prevent people from accessing the subdomain.

Comment: If you only want to show it as a folder under your top-level domain, why don't you simply make normal folders under your top-level domain? Your rule should work for what you describe, but there is simply no point in making a subdomain if you don't want to use a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If the 301-redirect works (for you), it will work for search engines, too.

See [Google’s documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en):

> 301 redirects are particularly useful in the following circumstances:
>   […]
>   People access your site through several different URLs. If, for example, your home page can be reached in multiple ways - for instance, `http://example.com/home`, `http://home.example.com`, or `http://www.example.com` - it's a good idea to pick one of those URLs as your preferred (canonical) destination, and use 301 redirects to send traffic from the other URLs to your preferred URL.

Comment: i just did a "site:" search for my website and i have noticed its indexed mydomain.com/folder/otherdomain.com will a robot.txt work or will that stop google from indexing the TLD?

Comment: @7O07Y7: When you visit such a search result, what happens? I assumed that it 301-redirects to the TLD. If this is the case, search engines will update their index, which may take some time.